# RPostgreSQL - how to export a value from r to postgresql table

Tags: r, postgresql

my `table(table1)` in database

```
Column |  Type   | Modifiers
--------+---------+-----------
 date1  | date    | not null
 line_1 | numeric | default 0
 line_2 | numeric | default 0
 line_3 | numeric | default 0
 line_4 | numeric | default 0
 line_5 | numeric | default 0
```

R console

```
> line1 <- 32+45
> line1
[1] 77
```

I want export these value (line1 = 77) into the table (table1) in line_1 column
and date1 column should fill with present date minus 1 day.

I tried with the below command for updating line1 value, but i am getting an error

s <- dbGetQuery(con, "insert into table1 (line_1) values (line1)")

Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RS-DBI driver: (could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  column "line1" does not exist
LINE 1: insert into table1 (line_1) values (line1)
                                              ^
)
Warning message:
In postgresqlQuickSQL(conn, statement, ...) :
  Could not create executeinsert into table1 (line_1) values (line1
)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I just formatted your question for you; learning how to do this yourself may make it more likely that other spend some time looking at the question.   In general, this looks like a _please program this for me_ question which are discouraged.

Comment: I tried with dbwritetable(RPostgreSQL) command...but it did'nt work

Comment: Actually i am a starter of R programming and PostgreSQL

Comment: Your question is **again** unreadable. Learn the help system, learn to format.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two issues in your code here -

First, you probably should be using dbSendQuery() instead.
This is because you are sending a command to the Postgres server.

Second, when you put text into double quotes, this usually tells R to interpret that as a string.  So when you are doing "insert into table1 (line_1) values (line1)", you are actually telling Postgres to insert "line1" into "line_1".  What you want here if you want to add only one value is a paste command.

Try this:

```
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("insert into table1 (line_1) values (",line1,")"))
```

And for your date:

```
date1<-Sys.Date()-1
dbSendQuery(con, paste0("insert into table1 (date1) values (",date1,")"))
```